# NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException ipad 1

Tags: ios, xcode

If i run my app on ipad 3 ios 6.1, the app works fine, but if I run it on ipad 1 ios 5.1, I get this error and the app crashes:

```
2013-02-09 12:20:58.434 Splash-it[531:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception     'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named    UIStoryboardEmbedSegueTemplate'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3583d88f 0x33461259 0x3583d789 0x3583d7ab 0x3322454d 0x332246bb 0x33224423 0x33122905 0x331b5c13 0x33224b1b 0x33224423 0x331b5839 0x33224b1b 0x332246bb 0x33224423 0x331b4fc5 0x332b5a5d 0x332b5b8f 0x330ec403 0x32f756eb 0x32f6f72f 0x32f3dac3 0x32f3d567 0x32f3cf3b 0x3352f22b 0x35811523 0x358114c5 0x35810313 0x357934a5 0x3579336d 0x32f6e86b 0x32f6bcd5     0x66aa5 0x5b598)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

What is the meaning of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embed segues are an iOS 6+ feature - they will not work on iOS5 or less

Answer (score 0):

as Rich Tolley wrote its "iOS 6 only", but you can try it's backport to iOS5 https://github.com/RolandasRazma/RRContainerView